# transition is affecting other pictures

Tags: css

I have created hover transition image with css. But when i hover over the first or secont image then other images pixel is changing in an instant. What is that and what is the solution for it ?

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/sdADt)** from codepen

This is transition css for my images :

```
.abo_im {
  float:left;
  width:170px;
  height:150px;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ;
   -ms-transition: all .3s ;
   -o-transition: all .3s ;
   transition: all .3s ;

}
    .abo_im img {
      width:100%; 
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;   
    }
    .abo_im:hover img {
      -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
        -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
        -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
         transform:scale(1.25);
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a JS issue to me.

Comment: @Paulie_D Check my answer, `backface-visibility` will fix this issue. Also what made you think it was a JS issue? (just out of curiosity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `backface-visibility` on the `img`, this will fix it.

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/x15302qg/)

Comment: This is good. But if i use `backface-visibility` then all pixel values ​​of the image is distorted.

Comment: @innovation Hmm, I thought that was an effect you wanted! Ha I will have a little look now. But that image was doing that before wasn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to your `.abo_im img`

```
.abo_im img {
width: 100%;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

See it [here](http://codepen.io/undefinedtoken/pen/AEcKf)